# Byte Array to Image object

Tags: java, arrays, image, byte

I am given a byte[] array in Java which contains the bytes for an image, and I need to output it into an image. How would I go about doing this?

Much thanks

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the question was for writing to an image file. This answer is for reading FROM an image file. Whats with all the up-votes?

Comment: The title says that, but the question says they have a byte array and need an Image, that's what this does.

Answer (score 26):

If you know the type of image and only want to generate a file, there's no need to get a BufferedImage instance.  Just write the bytes to a file with the correct extension.

```
try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))) {
    out.write(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
From Database.
Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("pictureBlob");               
byte [] data = blob.getBytes( 1, ( int ) blob.length() );
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
drawPicture(img);  //  void drawPicture(Image img);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it sounds like you already know what format the byte[] array is in (e.g. RGB, ARGB, BGR etc.) you might be able to use [BufferedImage.setRGB(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)), or a combination of [BufferedImage.getRaster()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRaster()) and [WritableRaster.setPixels(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setPixels(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[])) or [WritableRaster.setSamples(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setSamples(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[])). Unforunately both of these methods require you transform your byte[] into one of int[], float[] or double[] depending on the image format.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java docs, it looks like you need to use [the MemoryImageSource Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html) to put your byte array into an object in memory, and then use Component.createImage(ImageProducer) next (passing in your MemoryImageSource, which implements ImageProducer).