# Convert image byte[] to a file

Tags: java, image, arrays

I am trying to convert an image(png,jpg,tiff,gif) to a File on disk.When I view it after storing it on file, I cannot see the file.

Here is some code I have tried based on other forum discussions:

```
byte[] inFileName = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("c:/test1.png"));

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inFilename);
..String fileName="test.png";
Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer,"ISO-8859-1");
```

This creates a png file I cannot see.

I tried using ImageIO based on some other discussion but can't get it to work.Any help is appreciated.

```
    Image inImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(inFilename));
BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(100, 100,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(os);
//encoder.encode(inImage);
```

Comment: Do mine eyes deceive me? Are you **really** writing a PNG file with a text encoding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file

Answer (score 5):

You should write it to [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) directly.

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
```

Images are binary data, not character data. You should not use a `Writer`, it's for character data, but you should use an `OutputStream`, it's for binary data. The `BufferedImage` and `JPEGImageEncoder` are pointless as long as you don't want to manipulate the image.

Comment: +1 as I was unable to answer this question myself, was busy reattaching my jaw after reading the code...

Comment: @BlausC I have a use case for Android OS to copy a .png image as an app asset.  So rather than use IOUtils from Apache library, can you point me in the right direction to copy the image bytes to a file with Android methods, so I can use FileProvider() to share the image with another app user?  I am trying to copy image to a File in the app's internal storage directory.

Comment: @AJW: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+write+inputstream+to+outputstream --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/43157/157882

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do; read a PNG image and save it as a JPEG?

Your first code snippet is not going to work, because you are using a `Writer` to write the data. A `Writer` is only suited for writing text files. PNG and JPEG files contain binary data, not text.

You can load an image using the ImageIO API:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/test.png"));
```

And then write it in another format using the ImageIO API:

```
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("C:/test.jpg"));
```