# android: copy internal storage image to ImageView?

Tags: android, file, bitmap, inputstream, outputstream

Image is copied from assets directory to internal storage directory and new image is successfully found in the directory using Android Studio's Device File Explorer.  But UI is blank.  What am I missing here?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    private final String assetImage = "qtest1.png";
    boolean isDirectoryCreated;
    private ImageView myImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = assetManager.open(assetImage);
            File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
            isDirectoryCreated = dir.mkdirs();
            out = new FileOutputStream(dir + File.separator + "qtest1InStor.png");
            copyFile(in, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        }
        finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                   in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // NOOP
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // NOOP
                }
            }
         }

         File imgInStor = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "qtest1InStor.png");
         if (imgInStor.exists()) {
             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgInStor.getAbsolutePath());
             myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}    

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="testpng" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: First, make sure that your bitmap is generated successfully, if yes, then in your XML change width and height from wrap_content to 0dp, it will get the height and width via the constraint provided. Let me know If it doesn't work.

Comment: @Suraj Vaishnav I will try and let you know.  Ok, I added "if (bitmap != null)" in the Activity and then I changed the ImageView height and width to "0dp".  Same result, the UI is blank.

Comment: In your Relative Layout where you set your `android:layout_height="0dp"` also set    
 `android:layout_weight="1"` to show the image..

Comment: @amit notice in the code above, it's not a RelativeLayout, it's a ConstraintLayout: "<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout"

Comment: Add a `RelativeLayout` inside your `ConstraintLayout` which holds your `ImageView`