# Read image data from COM7 port in Java

Tags: java, port

I am doing a project in which I have to display the image captured from a camera chip on to the PC.

The image data is being sent through the COM7 port to the computer. (I have checked it using a dumb terminal program). Basically what I want to do is to develop a Java program that will read the COM port, get the image data, process it and display it on the screen.

What I want to know is how to read this image data from COM7 port in my Java program.

Comment: Not nearly enough information to answer. In what format is the data being streamed?

Comment: That is meaningless. In what *file or image format* is the data being streamed?

Comment: I am getting data from a micro-controller through the RS232 link.

Answer (score 1):

For the serial port portion of the problem, read the serial port like any other file.

- On 'nix, serial ports are named `/dev/ttySn` where n 0-3 for COM1 to COM4.  I'm guessing that if more serial ports exist, appropriately named files will exist on your system to access these too.
- on Windows you can just use the special file names `COM1`, `COM2`, etc.

As for actually reading the image data, as mentioned by others, you will need to know what format it is in.  You can try using `ImageIO.read()` if it is in one of Java's known file formats.  If it is in a raw bitmap format, you could try constructing a buffered image from the raw data by creating a BufferedImage from a Raster, and a Raster from an appropriate SampleModel and DataBuffer.  You will need to know the format of the bitmap data to do this, however.

Comment: The data format according to camera specification is:
Data format - YCrCb 4:2:2, GRB 4:2:2, RGB Raw Data

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start with reading the data from the port. For this, a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) could be useful.

Since you 'think' the data will be bytes... try the following:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

You could also check out a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file) post