# How to Get image from ComPort

Tags: java, python, jpeg

I have some problems in my work..
I have stored TTL serial camera images to MicroSD card successfully using Arduino UNO with the help of Adafruit Tutorial (learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera/overview) but when i m transferring that images through Zigbee transmitter, At the comport (Zigbee receiver) i m receiving random words. And i think its ASCII.
I want to save images receiving from comport to the folder of my PC.
Is it possible?
I have seen in some forums that use the java or python code, but i can't understand how to use it?
[Read image data from COM7 port in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117152/read-image-data-from-com7-port-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)
image = ser.read()

with open('/tmp/image', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(image)
```

Works only in Python 3, in Python 2 you need to use io.open. You may need to install serial-modul first if you don't already have it. I'm not familiar with the Arduino-C-dialect you need to send the image over the com-port...

Answer (score 0):

[Arduino IDE](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java)'s [Serial Monitor](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/app/src/processing/app/SerialMonitor.java) is using the [Serial](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/app/src/processing/app/Serial.java) class to communicate over a serial comm. port.

```
// Receive & send methods from the SerialMonitor class.
private void send(String s) {
    ..
    serial.write(s);
}

public void message(final String s) {
    ..
    textArea.append(s);
}
```

My suggestion is to reuse that (Java) code, but since the `Serial` class is designed for text-only communication you would need to encode the image bytes into e.g. Base64 encoding with [this library](https://github.com/adamvr/arduino-base64) and decode it on the PC.

If the transfer speed is important, and there is an Arduino binary-based serial communication library, you should use that.

**UPDATE**

You can read raw bytes from the serial port via the mentioned `Serial` class like this:

```
...
Serial port = ...;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // 1KB buffer
OutputStream imageOutput = new FileOutputStream(...);

// Wait for the image.
while (port.available() > 0) {
  int numBytes = port.readBytes(buffer);
  if (numBytes > 0) {
    imageOutput.write(buffer, numBytes);
  }
}
imageOutput.flush();
imageOutput.close();
...
```