# get byte array of image from inputstream of Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to receive a jpeg image in  android from a hardware via Bluetooth .
I want to read the inputstream and show the actual data from byte array.
my actual data looks like:

```
ff d8 ff e1 63 70 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00
08 00 00 00 0b 00 0f 01 02 00 06 00 00 00 92 00
.........................ff d9
```

I used this code:

```
 void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();


    beginListenForData();
    //ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");


}


void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
           {
                try 
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        final byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (byte b : packetBytes) {
                            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b)).append(" ");//there's no need to mask it with 0xFF. Don't forget to leave a " " between bytes so you may distinguish them.
                        }
                        Log.d("data","data"+sb.toString());


                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                //ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( packetBytes);
                               // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                               // image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });
                    }


                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
           }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();


}
```

What i am getting is that:

```
6163206339203564203264203138203...........
463206620666620643920
```

How to show the actual result(hex values) in logcat and then show the jpg image from the hex value??

I send jpg image data from camera using the following code:
main.cpp  http://pastebin.com/Tx8YkbYF
JPEGCamera.cpp http://pastebin.com/0jHQ8WvT

Comment: Did you check [Byte Array to Image File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file) ?

Comment: Yeah checked but got no result  @Daniel

Comment: would u help ?? @Daniel

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "show the jpg image"? Where do you want this image to be shown?

Comment: I want to show the image into a imageview. i tried more than 4 days. but i failed. @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

> (1) How to show the actual result(hex values) in logcat?

Since you already have the byte values, you just have to format these values according to HEX base. `String.format("%02X ", ...)` will do just fine:

```
final byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b)).append(" ");//there's no need to mask it with 0xFF. Don't forget to leave a " " between bytes so you may distinguish them.
}
Log.d("data: " + sb.toString());
```

> (2) Then show the jpg image from the hex value??

If you're sure those bytes are the bytes of a JPEG encoded image, you can decode them, as they are, into a Bitmap :

```
ImageView imageView = ...; //load image view defined in xml file
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(packetBytes, 0 , packetBytes.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Got the same result as previous... if u want i can provide the code which the camera uses for sending data.  @Daniel

Comment: May be the bytearray are not correctly received in my app. But i tried with another app it can receive the and show the jpg formatted data which starts ffd8 and ends with ffd9. What is my fault?? @Daniel

Comment: For camera: JPEGCamera.cpp-> http://pastebin.com/0jHQ8WvT     main.cpp-> http://pastebin.com/Tx8YkbYF

Comment: I have edited my question with the code that i used to receive data. @Daniel