# Image Hex string to byte[] convertion

Tags: android, image, hex, type-conversion

I have a hex string. When i past this hex string into a hex editor then if  save this as JPG format then it shows the JPG image.
But how can i convert the hex string into byte[] image and show the image into a imageView.
My hex string looks like:

```
 ff d8 ff e0 0 10 4a 46 49 46 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ff db 0 43 0 c 8 9 b 9 8 c b a b e d c e 12 1e 14 12 11 11 12 25 1a 1c 16 1e 2c 26 2e 2d 2b 26 2a 29 30 36 45 3b 30 33 41 34 29 2a 3c 52 3d 41 47 4a 4d 4e 4d 2f 3a 55 5b 54 4b 5a 45 4c 4d 4a ff db 0 43 1 d e e 12 10 12 23 14 14 23 4a 32 2a 32 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a ff c4 0 1f 0 0 1 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b ff c4 0 b5 10 0 2 1 3 3 2 4 3 5 5 4 4 0 0 1 7d 1 2 3 0 4 11 5 12 21 31 41 6 13 51 61 7 22 71 14 32 81 91 a1 8 23 42 b1 c1 15 52 d1 f0 24 33 62 72 82 9 a 16 17 18 19 1a 25 26 27 28 29 2a 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8a 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9a a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 aa b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 ba c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 da e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 ea f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 fa ff c4 0 1f 1 0 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b ff c4 0 b5 11 0 2 1 2 4 4 3 4 7 5 4 4 0 1 2 77 0 1 2 3 11 4 5 21 31 6 12 41 51 7 61 71 13 22 32 81 8 14 42 91 a1 b1 c1 9 23 33 52 f0 15 62 72 d1 a 16 24 34 e1 25 f1 17 18 19 1a 26 27 28 29 2a 35 36 37 38 39 3a 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8a 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9a a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 aa b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 ba c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 da e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 ea f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 fa ff c0 0 11 8 0 78 0 a0 3 1 21 0 2 11 1 3 11 1 ff da 0 c 3 1 0 2 11 3 11 0 3f 0 f3 9d c3 fb b4 2a ee fe 1a 6a e0 4b b4 c 2a d2 81 b3 a0 a4 2 3b f6 a6 67 22 9e a3 dc 6f e1 4b f8 53 1 7b 74 a4 eb d1 6a 46 1f 85 2f e1 54 f4 11 3c 3 26 b5 2d 2c 8c dc 91 84 a6 93 19 aa 22 58 97 6a 2e 5 26 dc f6 a6 59 13 fd 2a 9 29 c aa df 4a 85 a9 10 66 5 dc 73 95 a9 bb e1 4a e3 bd 2e 69 11 64 3f 1b 7b ad 27 1d 77 2d 1c d2 b0 ac 88 5f af de 5a 6f af cc a2 8e 69 f 46 27 fc 9 68 1f ef 2d 3e 66 1a e ff 0 81 2d 27 e2 b4 b9 a4 16 43 b3 9e eb 4a 7 38 1b 68 f7 82 c8 de d2 f4 b3 1f ef 2e 31 ec b5 ad 8f a5 68 5a 48 8 cf a5 31 bf a 5a 8c af 27 a0 22 ab c9 f5 14 ae d0 ca ad f5 15 3 fd 56 95 d9 3a 14 40 df c7 41 52 84 a5 7b 10 f d4 e2 91 87 14 ae 4 5b 72 3d e9 9e 49 ab 1 7c a3 ed 4b e4 e7 b5 2e 61 7 90 69 c2 dc d1 71 92 47 65 2c ae 15 6 58 d7 49 a6 e9 9 66 37 3f cd 2f f2 a6 98 d2 34 36 d1 b2 9b 2c 42 2a 17 14 80 81 d6 aa c8 b4 ae 5 66 5a 81 d6 81 58 aa 30 7 f0 d2 f5 1c 11 c5 42 b5 ae 48 dd de e2 8e bd 71 47 ba 1a 89 f8 8a 5c f5 e4 53 d0 41 f9 53 bf 2a 34 1 7f 2a b7 67 69 25 d3 ed 4f c4 d1 b8 1d 25 a5 9a 5b 26 14 c f7 35 63 15 65 86 da 4c 50 4 6d 51 30 fa 52 2 bc 95 56 4f c2 96 85 15 df ad 57 7f a8 a4 5 16 3f 4a 17 3e 82 96 a6 42 fe 54 ef ca 9a 10 ce dd a9 68 1a 1d 4e 5a 5d 2 e5 fd 3b 4f 92 ec e7 a4 7e b5 d2 db db c7 6e 81 23 5c a b4 86 89 31 4e db 4c a1 31 4d 34 8 61 15 13 a 90 2b 49 55 64 14 8a 2a bd 40 ff 0 4a 35 19 9b da 94 74 a0 c4 92 94 a 0 6f 7a 5c 50 4 82 b5 34 cd 2d ae 48 92 4e 23 fe 74 c e8 e3 8d 63 40 aa 30 29 f8 ad b 1d 8a 29 8 69 a6 e2 80 18 6a 27 a9 2 bc 95 56 4a 45 15 a4 aa cc b4 8a 33 f 34 a0 71 4f 43 1 f4 ea 2e 80 67 19 a7 a8 a0 d 9d 27 49 f3 88 96 71 f2 76 1e b5 d1 2a 60 60 74 ab 45 44 7e 29 45 31 8b 8a 29 8 4c 53 48 a0 44 4d 51 35 20 2b c9 55 9e a4 b2 ab d4 2c 29 14 63 53 d6 9b d0 c4 93 de 9a df ad 0 39 57 68 f7 35 b7 a4 69 3b f1 35 c0 e3 b0 aa 41 b9 d0 5 c7 14 f1 54 68 3a 9d 40 85 a4 c5 22 42 9a 45 20 22 61 50 38 a4 5 77 aa b2 1a 6 56 35 b 73 52 59 8c 69 ca dc d5 33 31 d4 f8 d7 27 26 90 1b ba 56 97 b8 89 a7 1c 76 6 b7 87 15 a0 d0 ea 5a 63 1d 4e a4 21 d4 52 10 94 d3 40 11 35 42 f4 80 ad 2d 52 97 a5 21 94 98 d5 76 90 d0 d0 5c cd ed d2 96 90 85 4f 99 bd ab 7f 48 d3 37 7e fa 51 f2 f6 14 20 37 c7 14 ea d0 b1 69 e2 98 87 a 7d 21 b 4b 8a 4 18 a4 2b 48 8 99 6a 7 5a 90 2b 4a 2a 8c fd 28 2 8c bc 66 a8 dd bf 97 19 34 86 51 fa 50 de 94 13 63 73 45 d2 fc cc 4b 37 dd ec 3d 6b a3 5e 2b 44 5a 43 a9 69 8c 70 a7 8a 4 49 4a 28 24 75 3e
```

Comment: check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/140131/3326331)

Answer (score 0):

check argument via assert or exceptions if the argument is not known to be safe.

**Edit:**

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexIn) {
    byte [] byteOut = new byte [hexIn.length() / 2];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexIn.length(); i += 2)
    {
            byteOut[j++] = Byte.parseByte(hexIn.substring(i, i + 2), 16);
    }
    return byteOut;
}
```

to set this image data `byte[]` on a `ImageView` :

```
public static void setImageViewWithByteArray(ImageView view, byte[] data) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Why need AsyncTask?? I just have a string of hex data mentioned above and just convert it to image then show this image to a image view. @Sagar Pilkhwal

Comment: And got an error - "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4069; index=4069" .Do u know why?? @Sagar Pilkhwal

Comment: Nope it doesnt work. java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range for byte: "ff" @Sagar Pilkhwal

Comment: This [post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/528306/java/java/Hex-Decode-Byte) talks about Value out of range for byte: "ff" problem

Comment: But i cant construct the image . Please i need a solution. anybody has any solution ???

Comment: edit you question and post the code by which you are converting image to hex.

Comment: I got that data from a hardware JPG camera.

Comment: You can see the details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658718/get-byte-array-of-image-from-inputstream-of-bluetooth/25661074#25661074

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how to turn hex string into int-value array

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
      String s="ff a1 23 43 1";

      ArrayList ilist = new ArrayList();
      //regular expression to solve any format of hexstring
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9a-fA-F]+)");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
      int index=0;
      while( (!m.hitEnd()) && (m.find(index)) )
      {
        String ms=m.group();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(ms,16);
        // add the value to list
        ilist.add(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        index=m.end();
      }
      // get an array from list, not as necessary,though.

      Object[] c = ilist.toArray();
      System.out.println(c[1]);

      return;
}
```

Then i assume it won't be hard to turn int into byte.