# Convert the ByteArray of an Image file back to an Image file

Tags: java, arrays, image

I converted an image file to byte array and then save as a BLOB in database but when i retrieve the saved byte array from database and converted it back to the image file, the image file is not showing.

converted image file to byte array like this:

```
File imageFile = new File("image.jpg");
byte[] byteArrayOfImageFile = new byte[(int)imageFile.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
fileInputStream.read(byteArrayOfImageFile);
fileInputStream.close();
```

converted byte array to image file like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg);
try {
    fos.write(byteArrayOfImageFile);
} finally {
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Here is an answer for this question : [Byte Array to Image File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580285)

Comment: You forgot to check the return value of the InputStream.read method, which [tells you how many bytes were actually read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-byte:A-).  Of course, the better way to do this is `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("image.jpg"))`, which always reads all bytes.